# Passing a string to a function that formats JSON jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a feeling this is very simple, however, I am having trouble getting this to spit out anything other than **undefined**

I would like to be able to grab the JSON object passing in a string to the function.  Is this possible with a function like below?

```
var dashboardData= {
"Dashboard": 
{
    "Total_Downloads":95,
    "Unique_Downloads":30,
    "Campaign_Threshold":1000,
    "Downloads_By_Date":[
        {"Downloads":6,"Date":"9/6/2012 12:00:00 AM"},
        {"Downloads":2,"Date":"9/7/2012 12:00:00 AM"},
        {"Downloads":9,"Date":"9/20/2012 12:00:00 AM"},
        {"Downloads":2,"Date":"9/22/2012 12:00:00 AM"},
        {"Downloads":6,"Date":"9/23/2012 12:00:00 AM"},
        {"Downloads":10,"Date":"9/24/2012 12:00:00 AM"},
        {"Downloads":1,"Date":"9/26/2012 12:00:00 AM"},
        {"Downloads":1,"Date":"9/29/2012 12:00:00 AM"},
        {"Downloads":3,"Date":"10/2/2012 12:00:00 AM"},
        {"Downloads":4,"Date":"10/5/2012 12:00:00 AM"},
        {"Downloads":1,"Date":"10/6/2012 12:00:00 AM"},
        {"Downloads":2,"Date":"10/8/2012 12:00:00 AM"},
        {"Downloads":4,"Date":"10/9/2012 12:00:00 AM"},
        {"Downloads":3,"Date":"10/10/2012 12:00:00 AM"},
        {"Downloads":1,"Date":"10/12/2012 12:00:00 AM"},
        {"Downloads":27,"Date":"10/16/2012 12:00:00 AM"},
        {"Downloads":2,"Date":"10/17/2012 12:00:00 AM"},
        {"Downloads":1,"Date":"10/19/2012 12:00:00 AM"},
        {"Downloads":1,"Date":"10/20/2012 12:00:00 AM"},
        {"Downloads":9,"Date":"10/21/2012 12:00:00 AM"}
    ],
  }
};

        function formatJSON(source, key1, key2) {

            var i, l,
                dest = [],
                row;

            for(i = 0, l = source.length; i < l; i++) {
                row = source[i];      

                 dest.push('[' + row.key1, row.key2 + ']');

            }

            return '[' + dest + ']';

        }

var downloads= formatJSON(dashboardData.Dashboard.Downloads_By_Date,'Downloads','Date');     

var output="<ul>";
output+="<li>" + dashboardData.Dashboard.Total_Downloads + "</li>";

output+="</ul>";
document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=downloads;
```

​

Comment: What is `formatJSON` supposed to be doing?

Comment: Your question is really not clear. Is this what you wanted to do? http://jsfiddle.net/jFzav/

Comment: agree with @Blender. WOuld do best if goals were outlined, not guesses from code that won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for the key1 and key2 properties of the row object, not the property that the keys represent.

dest.push('[' + row[key1] + ',' + row[key2] + ']');

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for.  I am sorry to all others for the unclear question.

Answer (score 0):

[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) itself has some formatting options. For example, you can indent it with 4 spaces by passing "4" as the third parameter: [Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/sja4p/2).

Comment: FYI  fiddle dowsn't write content in Firefox 16

Comment: no problem...learned something abot numeric argument, have only ever used `space` before